# HA-JDBC database password decryption in xml config file

Tags: database, encryption, passwords

I read the document in the website of HA-JDBC about database password encryption in the xml config file and I unable to decrypt the password when I connect to my database. So, it return me exception which is invalid user or password. The following is my configuration in my xml config file:

```
<xa-datasource id="Derby1A" weight="100" local="true">
<name>org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientXADataSource</name>
<property name="user">clientuser</property>
<property name="password">64:MTIzNDU2Nzg=</property>
<property name="portNumber">1527</property>
<property name="databaseName">Testing</property>
<property name="serverName">127.0.0.1</property>
<user>clientuser</user>
<password>64:MTIzNDU2Nzg=</password>
</xa-datasource>
```

I put 64 in front the encrypted password, so, it will decrypt the password by using Base64 decoder to decrypt the password. How to decrypt the password when connect to database ?
Thanks a lot...

Comment: Maybe you encoded you password wrong?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, the password defined in the ha-jdbc configuration is only used by HA-JDBC itself - these are not the credentials used when your application connects to your HA-JDBC cluster.  When you connect to the HA-JDBC cluster from your application, you need to specify the password either in your application itself (e.g. DataSource.getConnection(user, password)), or preferably in your application server configuration of your HA-JDBC datasource.
The credentials used in ha-jdbc configuration should have administrative privileges (e.g. drop/create tables, etc.), while the credentials used by your application are typically CRUD privileges only.